# Mat slide toggle true / false update in Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update a Boolean field of a Firestore document from `true` to`false` or from `false` to`true` as the case may be.

It seems to work fine when I activate and deactivate the button but in some it stops working and I have to press the button again.

Here my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ea3wme

**myComponent.html**

```
<mat-slide-toggle #toggle [checked]="domiciliario.estado" (change)="actualizarEstado(domiciliario.id)"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

**myComponent.ts**

```
actualizarEstado(key){
this.fs.updateEstado(key);
}
```

**myService.ts**

```
estadoChange: boolean = !false || !true;

updateEstado(key){
this.afs.doc('domiciliarios/' + key).update({
  estado : this.estadoChange = !this.estadoChange
})
}
```

Comment: In your service you're using the same `estadoChange` value across all of the `domiciliarios`. You need to toggle the `estado` property of the specific `domiciliario` being edited by the toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `estadoChange` of your service won't keep synchronous with your edited `domiciliario` item. If you want all items of `domiciliarios` to keep independent status of `estado`, you need to update each of them with the exact correspond status of their own  which means you should take advantage of value of `mat-slide-toggle`.

You can try with `ngModel` and `ngModelChange`.

```
<mat-slide-toggle #toggle [ngModel]="domiciliario.estado" (ngModelChange)="actualizarEstado(domiciliario.id, $event)"></mat-slide-toggle>

// component function
actualizarEstado(key, obj, e){
  this.fs.updateEstado(key, e);
}

// service function
updateEstado(key, estado){
  this.afs.doc('domiciliarios/' + key).update({estado});
}
```

refer fixed **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z2jpka?file=app%2Ffirebase.service.ts)**.

---

**Additional info:** 
Every time you changed an item will cause value change of the firebase, and lead rerendering all ngFor items, you should consider use `trackBy` to prevent from rerendering same items of it, see also **[docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor-with-trackby)** and  **[solution for ngFor performance question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249811/how-do-i-get-angular-2-4-to-update-existing-dom-nodes-instead-of-deletingcreati/46249932#46249932)**.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the approach, this works for me. An additional detail, when I include `BrowserAnimationsModule` in `app.module.ts` there is a slight flicker when I click on mat-slide-toggle: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hr7suh If you have any reference on how to correct it I would appreciate.

Comment: @PacoZevallos It's because you are rerendering all items. You can add a `trackBy` function to tell angular to stop rerendering same item all the time. see fixed demo in my anwser and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249811/how-do-i-get-angular-2-4-to-update-existing-dom-nodes-instead-of-deletingcreati/46249932#46249932